# How to pass 'context' to another widget outside buildContext widget

Tags: flutter, function, class, dart, flutter-widget

I have this code

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('All users'),
      ),
      body: StreamBuilder<List<User>>(
        stream: readUsers(),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasError) {
            return const Text('error fetching data');
          } else if (snapshot.hasData) {
            if (snapshot.data!.isEmpty) {
              // return const Text('no data to fect');
              return Container(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                child: const Text('no data'),
              );
            } else {
              final users = snapshot.data!;
              return ListView(
                children: users.map(buildUser).toList(),
              );
            }
          } else {
            return const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
          }
        },
      ),
  }
```

Then at this point

```
 return ListView(
                children: users.map(buildUser).toList(),
              );
```

I want to return data from another widget outside buildContext widget but the issue here is that I don't know how to pass the 'context' in the **users.map(buildUser).toList()** unorder to eliminate the error in the image below.

[image]

Comment: Where does 'buildUser' method locate? If you want to use helper method way, just pass the BuildContext as parameter of 'buildUser' method.

Comment: tried already but reported error at **users.map(buildUser).toList(),**

Answer (score -1, accepted):

try this:
Widget buildUser(User user, BuildContext context) =>

Comment: doing that I got this error **The argument type 'List<dynamic>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'List<Widget>'**

Comment: I got the error here **users.map(buildUser).toList(),**

Comment: using code such like this
Widget testWidget(String x, BuildContext context) => Container(
      width: 100,
      height: 100,
      color: Colors.red,
      child: GestureDetector(
        onTap: () {
          Navigator.of(context).pushNamed(CreateMatchPage.routeName);
        },
      ),
    );
works fine for me 
i used testWidget inside my widget tree and passed the context to it and it works well without any problem you can provide us with more code examples to help you

Comment: did you try calling the function like this: **users.map(buildUser).toList(),**

Comment: How do I create a widget for this ** users.map(buildMember).toList()**

Comment: when you use .map function you have to use anonymous function like users.map((e)=>buildUser(e)).tolist some thing like that, e in this case represent each element from your users list

Comment: please be clearer in your answer. It's really confusing

Comment: check the comments to see the full answer
my answer considered as accepted no need to clarify more
read well and learn how to apply solutions

Answer (score 3):

Create a class like bellow

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class GlobalContextService { 
  static GlobalKey<NavigatorState> navigatorKey = 
  GlobalKey<NavigatorState>();
}
```

now assign this key to the MaterialApp in main.dart just like bellow

```
return MaterialApp(
navigatorKey: GlobalContextService.navigatorKey, // set property
);
```

Now you can access the context any where you want by using the following line of code

```
GlobalContextService.navigatorKey.currentContext
```

Comment: not understood, elaborate please

Comment: its the method if you want to get context anywhere in the app without passing it

Comment: can you give me sample with main.dart

Comment: from your code the class **GlobalContextService** is not called anywhere in your code

Comment: oh check it now

Comment: It works lol. 
However change "NavigationService.navigatorKey" to "GlobalContextService.navigatorKey".

Answer (score 0):

Recommended approach ->User helper widget instead of helper method.

or
you can pass context as parameter to method